# Stripping a spike from rrdtool when removespike.pl doesn't find any

Tags: monitoring, munin, rrdtool

I know when rrdtool graphs (using rrdtool 1.4) network traffic and the host is restarted a spike is a pretty normal thing to see.  In the past I've just run that removespike.pl script that is hosted by the author and it strips the spike and I'm good to go.

The last few times I've rebooted removespike.pl finds no spikes, but it's obvious that there are spikes.  So my question is, how can I easily remove these spikes and get my graphs usable again?  Right now it's so skewed it's meaningless.

Comment: removespike.pl has settings .. Have you tried to increase the % of spikes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Spike Removal](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/SpikeRemoval) technique from Munin's FAQ.

It consists basically in editing the RRD to have a max value, then dumping/reloading in order for rrd to remove all the exceeding values.